# How to covert large, mixed cell arrays with strings to double matrix fast in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, printf, cell-array

I have many large cell arrays (about 10000x100 cells each) that contain character arrays, sometimes these are numbers as strings and somtimes they are '..' or 'x' or something similar. 
I want to convert these cell arrays to numeric matrices (double arrays), so that all "number strings" are numbers (doubles) and all the other entries zeros.

Example: 
I have:

```
C = {'-34635', '22', 'x', '..', '5'; '..' , 'x', '-343','1','..'};
```

I want:

```
C_new =  [-34635, 22, 0, 0, 5; 0, 0, -343, 1, 0];
```

I can do it with `str2num` or `str2double` but it is horribly slow. I have read examples about using `sprintf` and `sscanf`, but I can't get it to work.

Any tips/suggestions on how to achieve this **fast** are very much appreciated. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Using `str2double`:

```
C_new = str2double(cellstr(C));
C_new(isnan(C_new)) = 0;
```

C_new =

```
  -34635          22           0           0           5
       0           0        -343           1           0
```

2) Probably a quicker way is presented [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18509-cell-conversion-to-double) ([`CStr2String`](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26077-cstr2string)). But it works, if your cell array consists of the numbers only:

```
 reshape(sscanf(sprintf('%s*', C{:}), '%f*'),2,[])
```

3) You can test this `mex`-function [`str2doubleq`](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28893-fast-string-to-double-conversion) (`mex str2doubleq.cpp`). @SenorPenguin tested this function and found that it is faster. But there is a bug in this function (see comments in response of @SenorPenguin).

4) If you have MATLAB 2016b, you can test @SenorPenguin's answer. Unfortunately, `double(string(C))` does not work in my MATLAB 2016a.

Benchmark (1000 times repetition):

```
str2double(cellstr(C))     Elapsed time is 1.611320 seconds.
str2double(C)              Elapsed time is 1.612186 seconds.
str2doubleq(C)             Elapsed time is 0.027442 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this before and it works, thats true, but it is horribly slow. I am looking for a faster way.

Comment: About `sscanf` you see this link https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/18509-cell-conversion-to-double

Comment: I got the idea to use sprintf and sscanf exactly from the first link you posted. But I can't get it to work on my data just for the reason you mentioned, namely that my data does NOT consist of only numbers. Thats exactly my question. How do I solve it for a cell with not only numbers. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome. Would you like to test `str2doubleq`  function from http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28893-fast-string-to-double-conversion?

Answer (score 2):

With cellstrs:

```
C_new = str2double(C);
C_new(C_new == nan) = 0;
```

A new string datatype came out in 16b:

```
S_new = double(string(C));
S_new(S_new == nan) = 0;
```

Performance comparison:

```
>> C = {'-34635', '22', 'x', '..', '5'; '..' , 'x', '-343','1','..'};
>> C = repmat(C,5000,20);

>> tic; str2double(C); toc
Elapsed time is 83.301997 seconds.

>> tic; double(string(C)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.985841 seconds.
```

Comment: Good answer (+1). Would you check the speed for the [`str2doubleq`](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28893-fast-string-to-double-conversion)? In my computer `str2double(cellstr(C))` sometime faster, sometime slower than `str2double(C)`.

Comment: `>> tic; str2doubleq(C); toc;
    Elapsed time is 0.248111 seconds.`

As some of the comments mention, str2doubleq has some bugs.

    `>> str2doubleq('1,000.25')`
    `ans =
       0.2500 + 0.0000i`

Comment: Thank you. I had uptated my answer.